# Side border expands with height

Tags: javascript, css, border

I'm working on a resume; currently exists at [this site](http://bernsteinbear.com/cv). The side border is static at the moment, but I'd like either JavaScript or CSS to make it expand to the height of the section. Tips?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Tag `resume` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012/130720#128315).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have the border set on the `dt`, simply move the `border-right` declaration from the `dt` to the `dd` and change the `border-right` to a `border-left` and everything should look as you want it.

**edit**: of course, the padding you put on `dt` will also need to be transferred to maintain the same look.

**edit 2**: complete solution:

*remove*

```
dt { border-right:1px solid #999; padding: 0 26px 0 0; }
```

*add*

```
dd { border-left:1px solid #999; padding-left:26px; }
dd.clear { border: 0; }
```

Comment: I did that but then it sticks right next to the block of text. I like exactly how it looks now - but preferably dynamic. How could I get the pixel height of an element in JS?

Comment: You don't need it. Javascript is the wrong solution to this. See my updated answer.

Comment: How could I keep the spaces that used to be between the sections?

Comment: `dd, dt { margin-bottom: 15px; }`